# Installing powered switch inside the wall

Tags: switch, walls, network

My home was built in 2019 and the builder used cat6 cable for the phone lines. I would like to use those cables for their intended use of computer network cables. The access to the cables is on the outside of the house and are covered in a metal plate stamped with phone. This access entrance is located about a foot off the ground just left of the main breaker box. Since a local ISP just installed fiber optic cables, i would like to use that cat6 box as the entrance for fiber. I would like to install a mini temperature hardened switch in there and run Romex to its power supply installed in the same box. The switch and power supply will be held in place using short din rails. The dimensions of the space are 15"w x 11" h x 4"d.

My questions is putting a powered switch with its power supply inside a wall ok? Is this the best way to use these cat6 cables? My attic has blown-in insulation so i don't want to fish any cables in the attic.

Comment: The ISP will need to put in a box to convert from fiber to copper, which will also require power. Where is or will that box be? At that location you could put in a POE injector or a small POE switch and then run a single Cat 6 to the place you want to put the switch and put in a POE-powered switch. That way you don't have to run 120V to that box.

Answer (score 4):

Well this isn't a problem, but...

No, there's no way to install electrical equipment inside a wall except in a listed enclosure, and by "listed" I mean listed *for 120V in the enclosure*. NEC 110.2 requires using listed equipment (for AC mains), and NEC 110.3(B) requires you to use that equipment according to instructions.  So if the instructions don't allow 120V in the box, nope.  Generally boxes that do will provide appropriate enclosures for mounting receptacles.

I found the AT&T fiber modem to be *absolutely enormous*.  Bulky, stylish, made to sit next to a TV in a modern house, not to fit in a typical telephony punch-block enclosure.    You might be better off finding a different home for it, and then routing ethernet from the fiber modem location to the punch-block enclosure, and have your switch there.  Note the fiber modem typically has its own WiFi hotspot, so you might think about that. For guests if nothing else.

On getting power to the switch, "it's easier to teach a violinist to play the bongoes than the other way 'round". That switch *actually* runs on low voltage, and NEC requirements are pretty mellow on low-voltage low-power circuits being run through walls (doorbell or thermostat circuits are an example).  So I would find a location in a utility space where a wall-wart power supply can be plugged in and won't inconveneince anyone, and then run low-voltage DC cable to the punchdown box.

We get this same question *a lot* with security cameras, "how do I get 120V to <weird place on their house's exterior here>", and the answer is PoE or other low voltage method.

Add to it that an outdoor outlet requires GFCI protection, and that's not awkward lol.  Again not a problem if you're delivering low voltage power.

Answer (score 4):

Before you start, disassemble all the "Cat6 as phone line" outlets and verify very carefully that cable is of any use.
Most of the time, cat6 installed as phone line is unusable for network - daisy chained etc. You might be able to use the fragment from the box to the first outlet, but that's it.
Assuming the existing cable is already ruined, just plan your network in proper way.
You will need a spot with electricity, dry, not overly hot (attic may be out depending on climate), and easy access to rest of the house by eg. crawlspaces. Center of the house works well, can be basement.
If running by cable, remember it is *one* cable *per device*. No daisy chaining, no splitters. If you need more devices than router has ports, get a switch. Also recommended to get own router instead of relying on the ISP provided one.